# How to start activity at the top of stack instead of launcher activity in Xamarin android app

Tags: xamarin.android

I am developing an android app using Xamarin. In my app, Launch activity is started then I go to Activity B from Launch activity. When I pause activity B by clicking on "Home" button and try to restart the app, the app starts from Launch activity instead of Activity B which was paused most recently. I want Activity B to be started after I reopen the app.

How can I achieve this? Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can removed activity from the activity stack and finished when the user navigates away.

```
[Activity(Label = "Launch Activity", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
```

you should make sure that you add the `NoHistory = true` Activity attribute in your launcher.cs

To read more about this attribute follow below link

[property/Android.App.ActivityAttribute.NoHistory/](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.App.ActivityAttribute.NoHistory/)